# Ubuntu 20.10 ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-2nd-gen freezes when originial pen touches the screen

Tags: freeze, thinkpad, touchscreen

my ThinkPad X1 Yoga 2nd Generation freezes as soon as the original pen touches the screen. It worked with Ubuntu 20.04 and some updates ago on 20.10. Unfortunately I cannot tell after which specific update the malfunction appeared.

The tochscreen and Ubuntu work well, when I use the touchscreen with my fingers.

Have you experienced the same or similar issue? Did you solve it, if so, how? Do you have any advice how to solve or analyze the problem further?

## System Info

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

If you would like to have more information please say so in the comments.

## update:

It works again after an update  thankyou Ubuntu Team and Canonical

Comment: It works again after an update  thankyou Ubuntu Team and Canonical 